# WooCommerce: Sorting problem: Selected orderby value overwrites filter value

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, sql-order-by

I have a sorting problem in my woocommerce shop. I'm selling shoes in my shop and I have some filters which shows users shoes they like, for example: **shoe type**, **brand**, **size**, **color**.

All of them work well with the **orderby** dropdown selection even if I combine them all. But when a **size** is selected and for example **"order by price"** the **filter value of size** is overwritten **by the selected orderby value**:

Selected filter **size 10**:

`../shop/?filter_size=10`

Selected filter **size 10** and **orderby price**:

`../shop/?orderby=price&filter_size=price`

**Edit:**

If I choose first **orderby price** and then **size 10** there is no problem:

`shop/?filter_size=10&orderby=price`

I use: WooCommerce Standard **Widget Filter: "Products by Attribute"**.

Any ideas where this error could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had a copy of orderby.php in my child theme woocommerce folder which caused this error. After I deleted it everything was fine.